# Why echo and var_dump doesn't work in aws-sdk-php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-sdk

For debugging my amazon integrated site I have put echo command and var_dump functions in some of the source files of aws-sdk but nothing is printing.

I thought I might be looking at different source code but if I do any syntactical error (purposefully) in the code that will throw the error. Why is this? Is there something to do with composer? because I installed it using composer

Comment: Try changing the configuration on Apache error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: when there is any error in code echo or var_dump not work. I faced same issue earlier.